# How to fill space to border with in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, plot

I need to fill space between 3 graphs but I don't  understand how to limit the area on the graph y2

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = lambda z: (4 * z - z ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
y1 = lambda x: (8 * x - x ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
y2 = lambda c: c * 3 ** (1 / 2)
x = np.linspace(0, 12, 100)
z = np.linspace(0, 12, 100)
c = np.linspace(0, 12, 100)
plt.ylim(0, 4)
plt.xlim(0, 4)

plt.plot(z, y(z), color='blue', label="y=(18-x^2)^(1/2)")
plt.plot(c, y2(c))
plt.plot(x, y1(x), color='red', label='y=3*2^(1/2) - (18-x^2)^(1/2)')

plt.grid(True, zorder=5)

plt.fill_between(x, y(z), y1(x), alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill the space that is both above `y` and above `y2`, you can take the maximum of both. In order to only fill where `y1` is above `y2`, you can you the `where` parameter:

```py
plt.fill_between(x, np.maximum(y(z), y2(c)), y1(x), where=y2(c)<=y1(x), alpha=0.5)
```

You might need to use more than 100 points in the `linspace`s to avoid small regions without filling. For this image I used `np.linspace(0, 12, 500)`.

To have nicer labels, you could you latex format (enclose with $ signs, and add braces for the powers):

```
plt.plot(..., label="$y=(18-x^2)^{1/2}$")
plt.plot(..., label='$y=3*2^{1/2} - (18-x^2)^{1/2}$')
```

To get a square root symbol, use the latex function `\sqrt`. To have a backslash in a Python string, either the backslash should be doubled, or the string should be preceded by an `r` ([raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)).

```py
plt.plot(..., label="$y=\\sqrt{18-x^2}$")
plt.plot(..., color='red', label='$y=3*\\sqrt{2} - \\sqrt{18-x^2}$')
```

[image: resulting plot]