# How to fill the area with in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, plot

I need to fill the area between y1 and y but but I don't understand how to limit the area under y2

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = lambda z: (4 * z - z ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
y1 = lambda x: (8 * x - x ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
y2 = lambda c: c * 3 ** (1 / 2)
x = np.linspace(0, 12, 500)
z = np.linspace(0, 12, 500)
c = np.linspace(0, 12, 500)
plt.ylim(0, 4)
plt.xlim(0, 4)

plt.plot(z, y(z), color='blue', label="$y=\\sqrt{4x-x^2}$")
plt.plot(c, y2(c), color='black', label='$y=x\\sqrt{3}$')
plt.plot(x, y1(x), color='red', label='$y=\\sqrt{8x-x^2}$')
plt.plot([0, 4], [0, 0], color='yellow', label='y=0')
plt.grid(True, zorder=5)

plt.fill_between(x, y(z), y1(x), where=(y2(c) >= y1(x)), alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Isn't this about the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782232/how-to-fill-space-to-border-with-in-matplotlib)?

Comment: Yes,i still can't understand how to use method fill_between.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to fill between the minimum of `y1, y2` and `y`?

```
miny = np.minimum(y2(x),y1(x))
plt.fill_between(x, y(x), miny, where=(miny>=y(x)), alpha=0.5)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]